# How to fetch image url from HTML page and store it in a variable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Requiremnt, The image active on Screen should be open on model by clicking view inclusions button. I am able to capture the url of image in html but don't know a way so that i can store that in a a variable in a ts file.

[image]

Above image i am able to capture the url.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let space of xyz && xyz[i]; let j=index">
                    <div class="carousel-item active underlinecarosel" [ngClass]="{'active':j===0}">
                        <!--URL Captured-->
                        {{xyz[i][j].attributes.document}}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12 col-sm-12">
                                <img [src]="xyz[i][j].attributes.document" class="d-block ">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    </ng-container>
```

Above is the code through which i am showing images from backend.

Please suggest some way so that this url i can save it in a variable in ts. using which i can show image by clicking view inclusion button.

Comment: how are you able to capture url in html?

Comment: i have updated the code in question. Please check

Comment: Why don't you attach the event to your ``view`` button, which will open a **model** and pass the URL to that click event and set ``src`` to the ``<img>`` tag on the model.

Comment: button and image url are in a different container